# How to change "Document extension" in XCode 4 after creating a project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In my document-based project I left the 'Document extension' field default, and can't figure out where to change it now. Would I only be able to do it programmatically now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document file type extension is specified [in your Info plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107). You can either edit it directly, or edit your target, which includes select Info.plist properties—including the document types list—in its editor.